# mod_ssl alert handshake failure

Tags: apache, ssl

The failure is intentional and is because SSLv3 is disabled. A .NET client is defaulting to using SSLv3 and it won't retry with a supported SSL version without receiving an alert before a failure.

I've got OptRenegotiate set as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions, but my server is still returning an SSL handshake failure, rather than alerting handshake failure (then sending handshake failure).

Works:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect my.working.server:443 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
2414208:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
2414208:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
```

Fails:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect my.failing.server:443 -ssl3
CONNECTED(00000003)
2414208:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
```

Sole difference:

```
2414208:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
```

It's getting this alert to be sent that is the problem: I cannot seem to find a reference to it anywhere in the Apache documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> A .NET client is defaulting to using SSLv3 and it won't retry with a supported SSL version without receiving an alert before a failure.

That's not how SSL protocol negotiation works. The client announces the best version it is willing to support and the server then responds with the best version it can which is equal or lower to the clients version. If this fails some clients (mostly browsers) retry with a lower SSL version because they assume a broken server. But they use a new TCP connection for this, i.e. no kind of renegotiation inside the existing connection.

There is no such thing as a protocol upgrade, which is what you describe here.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be clearer. It's getting the alert to be sent that is the problem. When the alert is sent, .NET re-negotiates and connects

Comment: @user3668514: This behavior is a feature of the SSL stack. I don't think you can configure anything different from Apache to change this behavior directly. At least OptRenegotiate does only apply if there is already an established SSL connection, which you don't have. It might be that the configure differs if you use a different underlying OpenSSL version or it might be affected by the choice of ciphers or whatever so I recommend you simply compare both server configurations to find out what could cause the difference in behavior.

Comment: I think the problem is in OpenSSL. It seems so simple as the sole difference is the sending of an alert. But how/where this is done is a mystery (so far).

Comment: @user3668514: I consider the main problem the .NET application which has unreasonable expectations on how SSL should work..

Comment: I agree, but the end client refuses to change it. I think the error lies with how mod_ssl closes a connection (alert > fail, vs just fail).

Comment: @user3668514: I know that at least the Microsoft SSL stack (SecureChannel) almost never sends an alert but only closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.0 needed to be enabled on the server for it to send an alert before a failure. The .NET client receives the alert, and tries again with a secure protocol i.e. not SSLv3.